# One word request - Synonymous with noun "shreds" and connotative of squishy bits?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm writing a bit of a gorey scene, where the character in question is overcome with violent muscle spasms in his arm; his muscles flex and convulse and swell so violently that they basically tear apart his arm, into "_____"'s. I need some noun that fills the blank that is synonymous with shreds, ribbons, scraps etc, but is connotative of squishy bits, flesh, etc. Almost like a descriptor for intestines?

Comment: 'shreds' sounds good to me. or whatever serving size beef jerky comes in.

Comment: *quivering lumps of flesh*.  But I think that's not possible.  Did you ever try to take a strip of paper and pull from both ends and rip it into three pieces? Put as many "starter tears" in it as you like.

Comment: How about "sausage"?

Comment: [tattered/torn] tendons, [loose/limp] ligaments, [snapped] sinew

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Gobbet*** might work as an evocative alternative. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gobbet) defines it as "A piece or lump of flesh, food, or other matter". Unfortunately, it doesn't carry the same shape connotations as *shred*...

Answer (score 6):

This might or might not be useful to you, because it's pretty informal, but sometimes when people talk about video games, a character being damaged and exploding into lots of bloody lumps of flesh as a result is called being "gibbed". The bits themselves are called "gibs", which comes from "giblet". Giblets are the edible internal stuff that's in a fowl.

Not sure if you would want to use the word "giblets" in the context you gave, but it is a noun that makes me think of scraps of flesh.

Comment: Is that pronounced "jibbed"? It sounds good, but I wouldn't want to use it if people accidentally pronounce it "gibbed". That sounds a little goofy, you know?

Comment: It is pronounced with a "j". I think the word "giblets" is more widely understood to be pronounced with a j sound, but "gibbed" or "gib" isn't formal so the pronunciation might not be universally understood.

Answer (score 3):

I always like "ribbons" for such contexts, and "filets" is particularly connotative as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "[globs](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=tablet-gws&num=50&newwindow=1&client=safari&hl=en-us&biw=1024&bih=671&q=glob+definition&oq=glob+de&gs_l=tablet-gws.1.0.0j0i10j0.9132.10773.0.12136.4.4.0.0.0.0.449.809.0j3j4-1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..0.4.808.sGcWac1DNaI)"

> ## glob
>
> ɡläb/
>   noun informal
>   noun: glob; plural noun: globs
>   a lump of a semiliquid substance.
>   "*thick globs of melted mozzarella cheese*"